# Insertando Usuario con Multiples Roles Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formularios, controller, orm, model

Estoy tratando de insertar a la bd un usuario el cual posee múltiples roles, todo parece ir bien hasta que en la consola pasa un Rollback, a pesar de que los parámetros que estoy enviando y la forma parecen ser los correctos.

Los modelos

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

 has_many :user_roles, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
 has_many :news, dependent: :destroy


 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

 validates :password, :presence => true, :on => :create

 EMAIL_FORMAT = /\A(?!.*\.\.)[a-z\d_.\-+]{1,50}@[a-z\d\-]{1,50}\.[a-z]{1,30}\z/i
 PASSWORD_FORMAT = /\A(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(?:!|#|\$|%|&|\/|\(|\)|=|\?|\*|\.)).{8,32}\z/

 validates_format_of :email, with: EMAIL_FORMAT

 def has_role?(role_name)
    roles.any? {|role| role.name == role_name.capitalize}
 end

 def is_admin?
    has_role?("SuperAdmin")
 end
end
```

role.rb

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord

 has_many :user_roles, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :users, through: :user_roles

 SUPERADMIN = 'SuperAdmin'
 ESTUDIANTE = 'Estudiante'
 PROFESOR = 'Profesor'
 ADMINISTRATIVO = 'Administrativo'

 ROLES = [
     SUPERADMIN,
     ESTUDIANTE,
     PROFESOR,
     ADMINISTRATIVO
 ]

end
```

user_role.rb

```
class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :set_roles, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

 def index
  @users = User.all
 end

 def new
  @user = User.new
 end

 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "El usuario ha sido creado exitosamente"
    redirect_to admin_users_path
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "El usuario no se pudo crear, por favor revise los campos"
    render 'new'
  end
 end

 def edit
 end

 def update
  if @user.update(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "El usuario ha sido modificado exitosamente"
    redirect_to admin_users_path
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "El usuario no se pudo modificar, por favor revise los campos"
    render 'edit'
  end
 end

 def destroy
  @user.destroy
  flash[:warning] = "Usuario eliminado para siempre"
  redirect_to admin_users_path
 end

 private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
    :name, :lastname, :dni, :birthdate, :address, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, role_ids: []
  )
  end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_roles
    @roles = Role.all
  end
end
```

La vista

```
<%= render :template => 'admin/home/index.html.erb' %>

<%= render 'admin/home/messages' if !flash.empty? %>

<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Nuevo Usuario</h1>
</div>


<%= form_for [:admin, @user], url: admin_users_path([:admin, @user]) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name"> -->
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class:'form-control form-control-user', id:"exampleName", placeholder:"Nombre", autofocus: true, autocomplete: "name"%>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name"> -->
        <label>Apellido</label>
        <%= f.text_field :lastname, class:'form-control form-control-user', id:"exampleLastName", placeholder:"Apellido", autofocus: true, autocomplete: "lastname"%>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name"> -->
        <label>Nro. Identificacion</label>
        <%= f.text_field :dni, class:'form-control form-control-user', id:"exampledni", placeholder:"Nro.Identificacion", autofocus: true, autocomplete: "dni"%>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name"> -->
        <label>Fecha Nacimiento</label>
        <%= f.date_field :birthdate, class:'form-control form-control-user', id:"examplebirthdate", placeholder:"Fecha de Nacimiento", autofocus: true, autocomplete: "birthdate"%>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name"> -->
        <label>Direccion</label>
        <%= f.text_field :address, class:'form-control form-control-user', id:"exampleAddress", placeholder:"Direccion", autofocus: true, autocomplete: "address"%>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name"> -->
            <% if @minimum_password_length %>
              <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
            <% end %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password, class:"form-control form-control-user", id:"exampleInputPassword", placeholder:"Password", autocomplete: "new-password" %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name"> -->
            <br>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class:"form-control form-control-user", id:"exampleRepeatPassword", placeholder:"Password", autocomplete: "new-password" %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="First Name"> -->
        <%= hidden_field_tag "user[role_ids][]", nil %>
        <label>Roles</label>
            <br>
            <% Role.all.each do |rol| %>
                <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", rol.id, @user.role_ids.include?(rol.id), id: dom_id(rol) %>
                <%= label_tag dom_id(rol), rol.name %>
                <br>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group">
        <hr>
        <div class="col-sm-2 mb-2 mb-sm-0">
            <%= f.submit "Aceptar", class:'d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm' %>
            <%= link_to 'Cancel', url_for(:back), :class => 'd-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-default shadow-sm' %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>


<%= render :template => 'admin/home/indexp2.html.erb' %>
```

La salida en consola

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"f1jg/xg/DQiW+oX34onoM0aOPAmaWmjEgS8OeJigqi/8pzF4IbePgv1w/YG3gqvQVbZ9HvOKbiWP5HPnbBDK8A==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Nombre 2", "lastname"=>"Apellido 2", "dni"=>"123456", "birthdate"=>"2019-03-04", "address"=>"Direccion II", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "role_ids"=>["", "2", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Aceptar"}
Role Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" IN ($1, $2)  [["id", 2], ["id", 3]]
↳ app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:14
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
↳ app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:15
(1.7ms)  ROLLBACK
↳ app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:15
Rendering admin/users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendering admin/home/index.html.erb
Rendered admin/home/_navbar.html.erb (3.7ms)
Rendered admin/home/_topbar.html.erb (5.0ms)
Rendered admin/home/index.html.erb (205.6ms)
Rendered admin/home/_messages.html.erb (1.1ms)     
Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles"
↳ app/views/admin/users/new.html.erb:77
Rendering admin/home/indexp2.html.erb
Rendered admin/home/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered admin/home/_logout.html.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered admin/home/indexp2.html.erb (157.0ms)
Rendered admin/users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (595.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1633ms (Views: 1041.7ms | ActiveRecord: 19.0ms)
```

Comment: En el controlador revisa el valor que viene en `@user.errors.full_messages` y sabrás cual es el error que te está rollbackeando.

Comment: Gracias crack, el email que debe ser por defecto debido a ciertos parámetros no lo estaba tomando.